# Specify the order of passed callback functions parameters using bind

Tags: javascript, express, underscore.js, bind, lodash

I want to pass in a parameter to a call back function for certain cases. For example I have two routes that I want to point the same function. For the route that specifies a plural I want to allow multiple things to be deleted.

```
server.app.delete('/api/delete/sku', this.deleteSku);
server.app.delete('/api/delete/skus', this.deleteSku);

deleteSku(req, res, allowMultiple = false) {
  //... delete code here ...
}
```

I know this can be done with underscore and lodash like this

```
server.app.delete('/api/delete/sku', this.deleteSku);
server.app.delete('/api/delete/skus', _.bind(this.deleteSku, _, _, true));
```

But this feels ugly to me and I think it affects the readability of the code, especially if people aren't familiar with underscore.

I also know that you can specify arguments through native bind but that puts the arguments in the front of the function.

```
server.app.delete('/api/delete/sku', this.deleteSku);
server.app.delete('/api/delete/skus', this.deleteSku.bind(null, true));

deleteSku (allowMultiple = false, req, res) {  }
```

Now it just feels weird to rewrite `deleteSku` to handle `allowMultiple` first and it breaks if I don't do a bind on the singular route case.

The other option is to have both `deleteSku` and `deleteSkus` methods that essentially do the same thing but map to different routes. I was hoping there might be a better solution that could result in less code.

Comment: Well `.bind()` does what it does.  You can either use it the way it is or write or use something different that puts the args in a different place.  Or you can just declare a stub function that calls the real function with the args in the right place.  I'm not really sure what you're expecting to get here.  You seem to know what `.bind()` does and seem to know there are other options.  Yes, the underscore/lodash stuff is both ugly and not familiar to many.

Comment: Personally, I'd probably just use a stub function: `server.app.delete('/api/delete/skus', (req, res) => this.deleteSku(req, res, true));`  It's hard to beat that for readability.

Comment: Be very carefully with Express.  It can sometimes pass more than just `(req, res)` sometimes (I'm not sure in which circumstances) it passes `(req, res, next)` which could really mess up your default argument to your handler.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Yeah I was just hoping for a better option, possibly some feature / library that I didn't know about. I think I'll leave it with two different methods and just be a bit more verbose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.bind()` only binds additional args at the beginning.  I'd agree with you that the beginning is not where you want your `allowMultiple` argument.  So, `.bind()` just really won't do the right thing for you there.  There is no option built into Javascript to postpend the arguments rather than prepend like `.bind()` does.

Because I'm not entirely sure when Express passes a third argument to your callback `(req, res, next)`, I'd be very, very careful using a default argument like you are doing with a route handler.  It seems very likely that Express will pass that third argument and your route handler `this.deleteSku` will accidentally interpret it as the `allowMultiple` argument being passed.  Because of that, I'd suggest you do this:

```
server.app.delete('/api/delete/sku', (req, res) => this.deleteSku(req, res, false));
server.app.delete('/api/delete/skus', (req, res) => this.deleteSku(req, res, true));
```

Then, you tick all the boxes:

1. It's still one line of code.
2. It's entirely unambiguous and readable what it's doing
3. It doesn't rely on any third party library
4. It's completely safe from Express passing the `next` argument to your handler and confusing things.

Comment: @SimonLau-Yamauchi - did this answer your question?  If so, please indicate that to the community by checking the green checkmark to the left of the answer (and also earn some reputation points for following the proper procedure here).  If not, then please leave a comment below this answer about what you are still confused about.